# Integrating a multivariable function defined with logical operation

Tags: matlab

I have defined a multivariable function in Matlab as:

```
function f=test(x,y)

if x>=0 && y>0
 f=x+y;
end

if x<0 && y>0
 f=-x+y;
end

end
```

Now I want to integrate the function over *x* but with *y* fixed to be 1, so in the command window I wrote:

```
f=@(x) test(x,1);
integrate(f,-1,1);
```

Then I got an error saying:

```
Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical scalar values.

Error in test (line 3)
if x>=0 && y>0
```

If I replace all && by & with everything else unchanged, there is another error:

```
Output argument "f" (and maybe others) not assigned during call to "test".

Error in @(x)test(x,1)
```

I appreciate if someone can help me do this integral numerically.

By the way, I noticed the problems appearing here seem to be unique when in the definition of the function there is some logical operation. If I defined

```
function f=test(x,y)
    f=x+y;
end
```

and do the integral as before

```
f=@(x) test(x,1);
integral(f,-1,1)
```

It correctly returns 2.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function f=test(x,y)
f = (x>=0).*(y>0).*(x+y) - (x<0).*(y>0).*(x+y);
end
```